# Can't able to run a simple program on .net-core 2. Getting following error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to get started with .netcore programming. Followed the basic tut from asp.net website but failed.

https://www.asp.net/get-started

I get the error (attached) after dotnet run command.
[powershell_output](https://codeshare.io/5w3X9p)

This is my first ever program after a fresh installation of the latest SDK (as of now). I have tried console app and it works fine. Even a simple app with 'web' template works ok and display 'Hello World' in the browser. However, as soon as I add 'services.addMVC' to the app it breaks with the same error. I have done all my research and tried a lot of things, but not sure what is happening.

```
     NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\dotnetcore  md tryx


    Directory: C:\#NIN\dotnetcore


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       30/08/2018   1:15 AM                tryx


 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\dotnetcore  cd tryx
 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\tryx  dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.401
 Commit:    91b1c13032

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.3
  Commit:  124038c13e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\tryx  dotnet new webapp -o try1
The template "ASP.NET Core Web App" was created successfully.
This template contains technologies from parties other than Microsoft, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-template-3pn-210 for details.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on try1\try1.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\try1.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\obj\try1.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\obj\try1.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 9.24 sec for C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\try1.csproj.

Restore succeeded.

 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\tryx  cd .\try1\
 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\..\try1  ls


    Directory: C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM                obj
d-----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM                Pages
d-----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM                Properties
d-----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM                wwwroot
-a----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM            146 appsettings.Development.json
-a----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM            105 appsettings.json
-a----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM            626 Program.cs
-a----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM           1856 Startup.cs
-a----       30/08/2018   1:17 AM            242 try1.csproj


 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\..\try1  dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.
 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\..\try1  dotnet run
Using launch settings from C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\Properties\launchSettings.json...

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.RelatedAssemblyAttribute.GetRelatedAssemblies(Assembly assembly, Boolean throwOnError, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 loadFile)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.RelatedAssemblyAttribute.GetRelatedAssemblies(Assembly assembly, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationAssembliesProvider.GetRelatedAssemblies(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationAssembliesProvider.GetAssemblyItem(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationAssembliesProvider.ResolveFromDependencyContext(DependencyContext dependencyContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationAssembliesProvider.ResolveAssemblies(Assembly entryAssembly)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String entryAssemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services)
   at try1.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\Startup.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at try1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\#NIN\dotnetcore\tryx\try1\Program.cs:line 17
 ⚡ NIN@DATASCAPE  C\..\..\..\try1 
```

Comment: my simple project files... (https://app.box.com/s/kzsy7t5tzmg93ykqkhvxbyci1l5zgre7)

Comment: Please include all relevant code *within your question*, as per SO guidelines. This question and it's answers should remain relevant even when the links provided are no longer available.

Comment: @user35562 I've tried to build your project .  Run `dotnet clean` and then `dotnet run`. Lastly it will work as expected .

Comment: @itminus - Thanks! I would like to know why it's giving error at my end. This my first ever installation of .netcore. I even never had Visual studio installed on this system. This error still persists even after clean installation of .net core.

Comment: @cwharris - added powershell output as guided

Comment: i downloaded your code and used `dotnet run` it works fine

Comment: @user35562 have you tried to remove your `bin/` and `obj/` directories ,  and issue a  `dotnet run` command ?

Comment: The output mentions prompting the user to trust an HTTPS Development certificate. I’m willing to bet that prompt never occurred. I that’s the case, it’s *possible* that this argument exception stems from the “missing” certificate.

Comment: thanks, guys for all the advice... I think I have found the issue. Did you notice this in my project folder?  C:\#NIN\dotnetcore

The '#' symbol seems to be causing the issue. I created a new folder and tried and It worked fine. Seriously, it took me 2 precious days in order to wrestle with this. Anyways, I am happy that I have found it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, caused by special number sign **#** in the project path (C:\#WorkSpace\api\..etc), by moving to another directory, it will work normally.